# C: strcmp and stdin arguments with input size

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm writing a program that does certain functions depending on what argv[0] corresponds to
For example.

```
 else if(strcmp(argv[1],"wait") == 0 )
```

Works perfectly when I type 'wait 2', it executes the code located in that if-statement, BUT if I try to type just 'wait' **(only one argument)**, it **doesn't recognize it** and doesn't go to this function.
Why is it not working, despite the fact that argv[0] DOES match 'wait'? Thank you!

Comment: Please learn to use your debugger, it will help you immensely. (And why is some idiot voting everything down?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is not what you describe.

Comment: Suggest showing more of the code between `int main(` and `else if(strcmp`

Comment: For clarity, is "wait 2" the name of the program with 1 argument "2"? or is "wait 2" two arguments given to some unnamed program?

Comment: @chux Sorry, to clarify I do know argv[0] calls the program name, in my code the function strcmp takes argv[1], but, for explanation purposes, I wanted to display it with just the arguments 'wait' and '2', no program name before it. I have various other functions other than wait being called, (start, stop) etc. and all of those work because they take in the arguments 'stop' and another argument like '3' etc. This one is supposed to only take in 'wait', but only works with more arguments like 'wait' '2'

Comment: @user3295674: 1. You know that `argv[0]` is the program name. 2. Are we to assume `wait` is the program name? 3. Do you realize that by comparing `argv[0]` for `wait`, that assumes that you know that the program name has to be called `wait`?

Comment: Things are still not clear.  In your comment "in my code the function strcmp takes argv[1]", but the above post has `strcmp(argv[0],"wait")`.  This is a contradiction.  Post a small complete example of your code that shows the problem.  That will save us all time.

Comment: I changed it to match the line in my code. The program name is 'shell', argv[1] is wait. Let me know if there is still confusion.

Comment: 1) As other said "...despite the fact that argv[0] DOES match 'wait'?" certainly should be "... argv[1] ..." 2)  Strongly suspect others parts of your code that depend on `argv[2]` which is `NULL` when you enter only one argument.  Need to see more code to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[0]` is the name of the executable.

Probable want `argv[1]` where (after checking `argc`)

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems he wants the program name. `argv[0]` is more accurate.

Comment: @Ed Heal Sorry, to clarify I do know argv[0] calls the program name, in my code the function strcmp takes argv[1], but, for explanation purposes, I wanted to display it with just the arguments 'wait' and '2', no program name before it. I have various other functions other than wait being called, (start, stop) etc. and all of those work because they take in the arguments 'stop' and another argument like '3' etc. This one is supposed to only take in 'wait', but only works with more arguments like 'wait' '2'

Answer (score 1):

argv[0] is your program name. You must type argv[1] instead.

Comment: No, that's not what he wants.

Comment: You're inside of he's brain? He's talking about arguments. And who would have behaviour depended on program's name?

Comment: Why not? It's completely plausible. Why else would you need access to `argv[0]` ?

Comment: He might don't know that argv[0] is program name.

Comment: That explanation is in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I do know argv[0] calls the program name, in my code the function strcmp takes argv[1], but, for explanation purposes, I wanted to display it with just the arguments 'wait' and '2', no program name before it.